# Gesture recognizer for UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uigesturerecognizer

I have a tableview which is populated from core data using an

```
if let fetchCell = fetchedResultsController...
```

I'm  trying to pass data from all my tableview cells to the gesture recognizer's function so when a cell is swiped over, the recognizer will recognize it and send the variables over to the gesture recognizer's function so that I can work with them.

```
        var Swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipes:"))
        rightSwipe.direction = .Right
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(Swipe)
```

The above is simply adding the gesture recognizer to each individual cell.

```
func swipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    println("You just swiped the following: \(correct_string)")
}
```

The above is the actual function of what to do when a cell is swiped. How can I get a variable which was assigned to an individual cell in the `if let` to print inside the `swipes` function

Thank you. Hope I didn't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a separate gesture recogniser for each cell (which will, unless you're careful, cause problems with cell reuse), I would proceed as follows:

1. Create a single gesture recogniser and add it to the tableView.
2. When the gesture is recognised, in your `swipes` function, use the `sender`'s `locationInView(tableView)` to identify the point where the swipe occurred.
3. Then use the tableView `indexPathForRowAtPoint` to determine the `indexPath` for the cell where the touch occurred.
4. Finally, use the fetchedResultsController's `objectAtIndexPath` function to obtain the relevant `NSManagedObject`.

(Presumably `correct_string` is an attribute of the `NSManagedObject`.)

Comment: I actually love you! What I did was exactly what you told me, plus I wrapped it inside an "if" statement to check whether the object was returning "nil" or not. Works perfectly!!! P.S yes the correct_string is an NSManagedObject